# Find out whether no records have been created in the last x number of days

Tags: mysql, if-statement, max, intervals

Suppose I have a database to keep track of watering plants whose structure looks like this:

```
Table: "Plants"
ID     Plants
----------------------------------
1      Roses
2      Daisies
3      Sunflowers
4      Marigolds
5      Daffodils

Table: "Maintenance"
ID    Plant_ID    Activity    Date
-------------------------------------
1     1            Water      2011-09-09
2     1            Water      2011-08-02
3     2            Water      2011-08-15
4     3            Water      2010-07-01
5     4            Weed       2010-07-01
```

I am trying to write a query that will tell us whether a plant needs watering, and if so, how badly. In other words: if a plant has not been watered in the last 30 days, return a warning level of "Yellow"; if it hasn't been watered in the last 60 days, a warning level of "Red".

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
SELECT Plants.Plants, 
IF ( DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, MAX(Maintenance.Date)) < 30 AND maintenance.type = "Water", '',
  IF ((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, MAX(Maintenance.Date)) >= 60 AND maintenance.type = "Water") or maintenance.date IS NULL, 'Red', 'Yellow')
) AS `Water Warning`,
IF ( DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, MAX(Maintenance.Date)) < 30 and maintenance.type = "Weed" , '',
  IF ((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, MAX(Maintenance.Date)) >= 60 and maintenance.type = "Weed") or maintenance.date IS NULL, 'Red', 'Yellow')
) AS `Weeding Warning`
FROM `plants`
LEFT JOIN `maintenance` ON `maintenance`.`plant_id` = `plants`.`id`
GROUP BY `plants`.`id`;
```

But this returns a "Red" warning for "Roses", instead of the expected empty string, and has no conditions for Maintenance.Activity. Please note that this same query will also need to perform similar functions for Weeding and other activities, so filtering in the WHERE clause might not be the answer.

Here's what I'm after:

```
Results
ID     Plants        "Water Warning"  "Weed Warning"
----------------------------------------------------
1      Roses               ""             "Red"
2      Daisies           "Yellow"         "Red"
3      Sunflowers         "Red"           "Red"
4      Marigolds          "Red"            ""
5      Daffodils          "Red"           "Red"
```

Comment: "I'm dramatically oversimplifying the actual query I'm working on for the sake of clarity, so if there's a punctuation problem or something in what I've typed here, that's not what's causing the problem." Then re-run your tests with the simplified testcase, so that we know there's not some trivial copying error before we start working on it for you. As far as this question is concerned, _these are your real queries_.

Comment: I've edited the question as per your suggestion. I hope it's not to complex now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really hoping there's a more elegant solutions, but this works:

```
SELECT 
`plants`.`plants`,
IF((MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Water',
        `maintenance`.`date`,
        NULL)) IS NULL) OR ((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,
            MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Water',
                `maintenance`.`date`,
                NULL)))) > 30),
    (IF((MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Water',
            `maintenance`.`date`,
            NULL)) IS NULL) OR ((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,
                MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Water',
                    `maintenance`.`date`,
                    NULL)))) > 90),
        'red',
        'yellow')),
    '') AS `Water Warning`,
IF((MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Weed',
        `maintenance`.`date`,
        NULL)) IS NULL) OR ((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,
            MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Weed',
                `maintenance`.`date`,
                NULL)))) > 30),
    (IF((MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Weed',
            `maintenance`.`date`,
            NULL)) IS NULL) OR ((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,
                MAX(IF(`maintenance`.`type` = 'Weed',
                    `maintenance`.`date`,
                    NULL)))) > 90),
        'red',
        'yellow')),
    '') AS `Weed Warning`
FROM
`plants`
    LEFT JOIN
`maintenance` ON `maintenance`.`plant_id` = `plants`.`id`
GROUP BY `plants`.`id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the statement bellow, you just need to join the table with the plants names.

```
SELECT *, 

CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, DATE) >= 60 THEN 'RED'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, DATE) >= 30 THEN 'YELLOW'
END AS FLAG
FROM test_table
```

Comment: Sorry for being as another answerer, but your answer is not diff from the OP.

Answer (score -1):

**Actual data**

```
mysql> select * from Plants;
+------+------------+
| ID   | Plants     |
+------+------------+
|    1 | Roses      |
|    2 | Daisies    |
|    3 | Sunflowers |
|    4 | Marigolds  |
|    5 | Daffodils  |
+------+------------+

mysql> select * from Maintenance;
+----+----------+----------+------------+
| ID | Plant_ID | Activity | Date       |
+----+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 |        1 | Water    | 2011-09-09 |
|  2 |        1 | Water    | 2011-08-02 |
|  3 |        2 | Water    | 2011-08-15 |
|  4 |        3 | Water    | 2010-07-01 |
|  5 |        4 | Weed     | 2010-07-01 |
+----+----------+----------+------------+
```

```
SELECT
Plants.Plants,
COALESCE(
CASE mt.Activity='Weed'
  WHEN 1 THEN
    CASE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, mt.last_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
      WHEN 1 THEN ''
      ELSE
        CASE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, mt.last_date) BETWEEN 30 AND 60
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Yellow'
        ELSE NULL
        END
    END
END, 'Red') AS "Weed Warning",
COALESCE(
CASE mt.Activity='Water'
  WHEN 1 THEN
    CASE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, mt.last_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
      WHEN 1 THEN ''
      ELSE
        CASE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, mt.last_date) BETWEEN 30 AND 60
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Yellow'
        ELSE NULL
        END
    END
END, 'Red') AS "Water Warning"
FROM Plants
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT Plant_ID, Activity, MAX(Date) AS last_date
  FROM Maintenance
  GROUP BY Plant_ID, Activity) AS mt ON Plants.ID=mt.Plant_ID
GROUP BY Plants.ID;
```

**Results**

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+
| Plants     | Weed Warning | Water Warning |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
| Roses      | Red          |               |
| Daisies    | Red          |               |
| Sunflowers | Red          | Red           |
| Marigolds  | Red          | Red           |
| Daffodils  | Red          | Red           |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

**Notes for OP**

1. You have posted wrong results
2. You have refer to nonexistence column `type`
3. You did not take care on table name case sensitive

Comment: Your answer is interesting, but in my final query the actual dates will be variables defined by the end user. From my understanding, I don't think this approach would work then. Sorry I didn't make that clear in my original post.

Comment: Did you try? And what do you mean user provide actual date? (I don't see any difference)

Comment: The "red" and "yellow" intervals will be different numbers. So it could be 20 days is a yellow warning, and 100 days is a red warning.

Comment: I edited the question quite a bit. I hope you'll stick around and try and answer it. You clearly know your stuff!

Comment: This isn't working. :(

If I add a record for 'Weed' on Roses with a date of yesterday, it still comes up with a red warning.

Comment: did you realised your test data and expected results are not tally?